# My audio output is captured by audio input

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

When I use video conferencing services, people told me about an echoing problem.

I have made a test and recorded audio in audacity during video conference and playing some music in VLC.

Both the music output and video conference output were recorded. So somehow my audio output is directed to my audio input.

This is happening **both with headphones and speakers**.
Any ideas why? How can I find it out and prevent this from happening on 18.04 LTS?

edit: There is no loopback device in alsamixer.